# Multi-level headings in TableForm?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to create multi-level headings in the TableForm, but cannot find functionality to do it:

[image]

Comment: No such functionality that I am aware of in `TableForm`. Use `Grid` instead.

Comment: @MarcoB Can Grid do everything TableForm can do?

Comment: Yes, and much more. You do have to set it up yourself though. See the example in my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some proper `Dividers` magic, combined with a clever use of `SpanFromAbove`, courtesy of [user6014](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137133/multi-level-headings-in-tableform#comment370159_137135), which reproduces exactly the desired layout:

```
Grid[
  {{"", "Region 1", SpanFromLeft, "Region 2", SpanFromLeft}, 
   {SpanFromAbove, "North", "South", "North", "South"},
   {"apples", 1, 2, 3, 4},
   {"pears", 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {"oranges", 9, 10, 11, 12}},
  Dividers -> {{{False, True}}, {False, True, True, False}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[Mr.Wizard's suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137133/multi-level-headings-in-tableform#comment370163_137135), instead, achieves the same goal using `Item` inside the Grid, which renders the addressing of a single cell *vastly* easier. This one goes straight in my MMA scrapbook:

```
Grid[
  {{Item["", Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}], "Region 1", SpanFromLeft, "Region 2", SpanFromLeft},
   {"", "North", "South", "North", "South"},
   {"apples", 1, 2, 3, 4},
   {"pears", 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {"oranges", 9, 10, 11, 12}},
  Dividers -> {{{False, True}}, {False, True, True, False}}
]
```

Comment: **Bonus homework:** add the dividers exactly as shown in the OP's example.

Comment: Crikey that was fast!  LOL :D  Oh, you've still got an extra bit of divider there to the upper left if you want an A+ ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hehe full disclosure: I was working on it already :-) Yep that's the one that's hurting by brain. I am not sure that I really *understand* `Dividers`...

Comment: Consider, `Grid[{{"", "Region 1", SpanFromLeft, "Region 2", 
   SpanFromLeft}, {SpanFromAbove, "North", "South", "North", 
   "South"}, {"apples", 1, 2, 3, 4}, {"pears", 5, 6, 7, 
   8}, {"oranges", 9, 10, 11, 12}}, 
 Dividers -> {{{False, True}}, {False, True, True, False}}]` which addresses the upper-left

Comment: @MarcoB Hint: use `Item` and `Frame`

Comment: @user6014 Oooh, that's good! That `SpanFromAbove`, that's clever! I'll add it to my answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: @MarcoB Yeah that surely is the better way.  Nevertheless for other applications my mundane approach can be helpful: `Item["", Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I *very much* like yours for its versatility. I added both for future reference.